# JS FileReader - I would like read file as reader.readAsBinaryString(file); but i have to wait for result how do this?

Tags: javascript, filereader

JS FileReader - I would like read file as  reader.readAsBinaryString(file); but i have to wait for result how do this

Comment: MDN contains an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString#example

Comment: readAsBinaryString is deprecated, better to read it as arraybuffer...
`file.arrayBuffer().then(fn)`